# Swift 2.0 - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

When I try running the button the app crashes and I get an error saying **unrecognized selector sent to instance** I think it has to do with the `throws` and `try` but when I get rid of them I get other errors saying: **Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled** when I say `let object3 = query3.getFirstObject()`.

```
@IBAction func post(sender: UIButton!) throws {
    print(event)
    let query3: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "NewsClass3")
    query3.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    let object3 = try query3.getFirstObject()

    var Description3 = object3["Description"] as! String
    var event3  = object3["EventNumber"] as! String
    let news4 = PFObject(className: "NewsClass4")
    news4["EventNumber"] = event3
    news4["Description"] = Description3

    news4.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            print("The event has been posted", terminator: "")
        } else {
            print("the post failed", terminator: "")
        }


}
```

Here is the code of my whole project:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource,    UIPickerViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
let pickerData = ["Fire","Oil Spill","Earthquake"]


var event: String!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: - Delegates and data sources
//MARK: Data Sources
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}
//MARK: Delegates
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    event = pickerData[row]
}

@IBAction func post(sender: UIButton!) throws {
    print(event)
    let query3: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "NewsClass3")
    query3.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    let object3 = try query3.getFirstObject()

    var Description3 = object3["Description"] as! String
    var event3  = object3["EventNumber"] as! String
    let news4 = PFObject(className: "NewsClass4")
    news4["EventNumber"] = event3
    news4["Description"] = Description3

    news4.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            print("The event has been posted", terminator: "")
        } else {
            print("the post failed", terminator: "")
        }


    }


    let query2: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "NewsClass")
    query2.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    let object2 = try query2.getFirstObject()

    var Description2 = object2["Description"] as! String
    var event2  = object2["EventNumber"] as! String
    let news3 = PFObject(className: "NewsClass3")
    news3["EventNumber"] = event2
    news3["Description"] = Description2
    news3.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            print("The event has been posted", terminator: "")
        } else {
            print("the post failed", terminator: "")
        }


    }

    let query1: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "NewsClass")
    query1.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    let object1 = try query1.getFirstObject()

    var Description1 = object1["Description"] as! String
    var event1  = object1["EventNumber"] as! String
    let news2 = PFObject(className: "NewsClass2")
    news2["EventNumber"] = event1
    news2["Description"] = Description1
    news2.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            print("The event has been posted", terminator: "")
        } else {
            print("the post failed", terminator: "")
        }


    }
    let news1 = PFObject(className: "NewsClass1")
    news1["EventNumber"] = event
    news1["Description"] = textView.text
    news1.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            print("The event has been posted", terminator: "")
        } else {
            print("the post failed", terminator: "")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Read the most excellent message.  It's trying to tell you something!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try creating a separate `@IBAction` to call

```
do {
    try post()
} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

?

(You would need to change `post` to a normal method that does not require any parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you can't have an @IBAction that throws, it changes the signature and won't be found by name.

Remove the throws tag and make sure you handle any errors in the action.